# GridView AllowPaging on asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a gridview and I have enabled paging and added the event handler. Everything is working fine except I have to press each number twice for it to update.

Below is the code I am using for the initial load and the the call for the pagechanging event handler

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            query = "SELECT log_id, use_username AS `Username`, log_type AS `Type`, "
                + "log_description AS `Description`, DATE_FORMAT(log_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date Created`, "
                + "DATE_FORMAT(log_time, '%H:%i') AS `Time Created` FROM log l, users u "
                + "WHERE l.log_userID = u.use_id";
            new DatabaseWork().loadGrid(query, tblLog);
            if (tblLog.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                lblNoData.Visible = true;
            }

        }

protected void tblLog_PageChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            new DatabaseWork().loadGrid(query, tblLog);
            tblLog.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        }
```

Below is the code being used to bind the data to the datagird which is being called from both the methods above

```
public void loadGrid(string query, GridView tblGrid)
        {
            using (DatabaseWork db = new DatabaseWork())
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.conn))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        tblGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        tblGrid.DataBind();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Everything is working fine except that each page number has to be pressed twice and I can't understand why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, there's no update panels just a normal ASP form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put this page postback condition before your query `If(!Page.IspostBack)`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      If(!Page.IspostBack)
      {
        query = "SELECT log_id, use_username AS `Username`, log_type AS `Type`, "
            + "log_description AS `Description`, DATE_FORMAT(log_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date Created`, "
            + "DATE_FORMAT(log_time, '%H:%i') AS `Time Created` FROM log l, users u "
            + "WHERE l.log_userID = u.use_id";
        new DatabaseWork().loadGrid(query, tblLog);
        if (tblLog.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            lblNoData.Visible = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
protected void tblLog_PageChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
       query = "SELECT log_id, use_username AS `Username`, log_type AS `Type`, "
        + "log_description AS `Description`, DATE_FORMAT(log_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Date Created`, "
        + "DATE_FORMAT(log_time, '%H:%i') AS `Time Created` FROM log l, users u "
        + "WHERE l.log_userID = u.use_id";

        new DatabaseWork().loadGrid(query, tblLog);
        tblLog.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it is getting an exception 'The CommandText property has not been initialised on the da.fill(ds); section of the class that loads the grid.

Comment: @Boardy; check edit part, tblLog_PageChanging should be look like that is edit part in my answer.

Comment: @Muhammmad Akhtar, thanks for your help. Sorry about this, but I have done what you have suggested and it is still requiring me to press each number twice to get the page to update.

Comment: @Muhammaad Akhtar Thanks you were right, the only thing I also needed to change was to revert the last two lines in the page changing event so it does the page index first then callsthe loadGrid method from the DatabaseWork class last.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that the `Page_Load` is executing before the `GridView_PageChanging`.

Try to load your data if the page is loaded for the first time using the [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property.